# Q: Python script into ececutable NOT WORKING (pyinstaller / cx_Freeze)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I tried to convert a python script called [table.py](https://github.com/1BenEz1/eToro-Table-Gen/blob/master/table.py) to .exe
The scripts imports `openpyxl, pandas, dataframe_image`
I've tried using the modules in the title as so:

***pyinstaller:*** I ran: `pyinstaller --onefile -windowed table.py` . When I click the executable there's a popup message saying `Failed to execute script table`

***cx_Freeze:*** I ran `python setup.py build_exe`

it printed `error: The baseline image directory does not exist. This is most likely because the test data is not installed. You may need to install matplotlib from the source to get the test data.`

so I followed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62828976/cx-freeze-error-baseline-image-directory-does-not-exist) and ran:

```
pip install "numpy<1.18.3" "pillow<7"
python setup.py build_exe --excludes=matplotlib.tests,numpy.random._examples
```

and It poped up this message:

[image]

Anyone got any ideas on how to proceed now?

Comment: Try installing the **pywin32** module. https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/ and then compile your exe using pyinstaller. It might work

Comment: @ProChess I already have this module..